# How can I run a job on Rundeck for each user in the list?

Tags: rundeck

I want to create a scheduled job on Rundeck. Rundeck Job runs the script that does some staff for a single user I have in my list.

So job has an input parameter - username. I need to run that job for all users in my list, but not to process it in one job execution. I need a separate job execution for each user.

```
Providing an example to make it more clear:
For instance, I have 3 users: user1, user2, user3.

    
I have a job that does some processing for that users and running it with parameter (unsername). 
I need to create a scheduled job that will be run for each user.

 1. Running job with user1 parameter
 2. Running job with user2 parameter
 3. Running job with user3 parameter
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: HI! Could you elaborate? (maybe with a job definition example to take a look) So, that user list are rundeck users or other users? Also, you can use ${job.username} environment variable to get the current user of a job.

Comment: Hi! The thing is I could not find any instructions how to create such job.

These are not rundeck users. Users are domain specific, some web app users.  Job requires input parameter that is a user (web app user). So I have a list of such users. For each user I need to run that job (scheduled job). I do not know how to do that. How to tell the job to run separate execution for each user.



Hope this made things more clear! Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

You can design a workflow with a list option to use on any step (like command, inline-script or script), I did an example with a list option (users) and example inline-script that do some action for each user, the job is scheduled.

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='users' required='true' value='alice,bob,charlie,david' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e62a25a0-b67c-4bb7-8721-c96b7e4cb9f5</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobEXAMPLE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <schedule>
      <month month='*' />
      <time hour='12' minute='0' seconds='0' />
      <weekday day='*' />
      <year year='*' />
    </schedule>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/bash

myusers=@option.users@
Field_Separator=$IFS
 
# set comma as the internal field separator for the string list
IFS=,
for value in $myusers;
do
    echo "action for $value"
done
 
IFS=$Field_Separator]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e62a25a0-b67c-4bb7-8721-c96b7e4cb9f5</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ylZ.jpg) the result.

Maybe [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#job-options) interest you. Also, [data values](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/key-value-data.html#key-value-data) work in this case.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but it was an option. Thanks, MegaDrive68k!